# Different next states for same current state?

Tags: state-machine, fsm

So I'm working on this state machine which is supposed to emulate a sequence as follows:

[state machine table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BhUh.png)

However, the state 00 goes to both 01 and 10 at different times. How can I design a circuit that allows me to go from the same initial state to two different next states?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the table you shared, I'm assuming that this machine wants to iterate in the loop `00`->`01`->`00`->`10` an again. In this case, your machine can be modeled using 4 states instead of just 3. These states are:

1. `A` represents `00` but when the previous state was `10`
2. `B` represents `01`
3. `C` represents `00` but when the previous state was `01`
4. `D` represents `10`

With `A` as the initial state, your table will then be:

| S | S' |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| C | D |
| D | A |

If you want to use the original values, then you must build a circuit that for each of these new states gives you those values. This circuit would be in this case:

| S | V |
| --- | --- |
| A | 00 |
| B | 01 |
| C | 00 |
| D | 10 |